# Froala Editor - Image Upload Event Not working - Angular 9

Tags: angular9, froala

Hello

```
   public options: Object = {
      events: {
        'froalaEditor.image.beforeUpload': function(e, editor, images) {

            alert('')
        }
    }
}
```

after uploading image event is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to install axios into the project to help with sending the request:

For that run the following command

```
npm install axios
```

After that, you have a couple that allows image upload to servers, but the most important is that, the imageUpload property must be set to true, see code snippet below for more:

```js
public options: Object = {
  charCounterCount: true,
  imageUpload: true,
  imageUploadMethod: 'POST',
  // Set max image size to 5MB.
  imageMaxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  events: {
    'froalaEditor.image.beforeUpload': function(e, editor, images): any {
      // Before image is uploaded
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('image', images[0]);

      axios.post('your_imgur_api_url', data, {
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'your_imgur_client_id/api_key',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        }
      }).then(res => {
        editor.image.insert(res.data.data.link, null, null, editor.image.get());
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```